# Responsive website: How to get rid of horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: width, horizontal-scrolling, css

I am currently creating a responsive website. I noticed there is an issue with empty space on the right as you scrolling horizontally. I can remove the horizontal scroll by adding `overflow-x: hidden`. But it will not work on mobile devices such as iPhone and iPad.

So, I tried to add `min-width` because it will help to get rid of empty space. But I can't put `min-width` on full.css (e.g. `min-width:1000px;`) because it will set to full-width - see example below:

full.css

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

responsive.css (less than 1000px)

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I was wondering if you know how to fix this issue? Let me know if you have a better option for it. Or should I create a new wrapper id?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Every now and then I have this problem, and a big part of solving the problem is identifying the element that's the culprit. I just came up with this little jQuery script you can run in your browser's JavaScript console to find which elements are wider than the body width, causing that annoying scrollbar to appear.

```js
$.each( $('*'), function() { 
    if( $(this).width() > $('body').width()) {
        console.log("Wide Element: ", $(this), "Width: ", $(this).width()); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: An adapted version: `$.each($('*'), function() { if ($(this).width() > $('body').width()) { console.log($(this).get(0)); } }).length;` -- By logging out the elements directly, you can more easily highlight them on hover in your console (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Very useful snippet, still saving me time in 2019.

Answer (score 23):

You Can hide the horizontal overflow using css code (and then the horizontal scroll bar will never show up again):

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: It works well at my site. Eventually this helps saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 6):

Often times it's a matter of a single element which can cause the page to get the horizontal scrollbar. That can be a pain, but you can easily find out the offending element by this simple css trick

```
* {border:1px solid red}
```

You can also add the following properties if the element is hidden.

> opacity: 1 ; visibility: visible;

Demo :https://codepen.io/i_abhi/pen/eYzpBjr

Comment: The sheer simplicity, universality, and memorability of this solution really make it excellent! Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Link to the page? Chances are there is some kind of element inside the wrapper that is breaking past the browser window.

Often times it is with padding and widths. Keep in mind if you have an element inside the wrapper that is set to say 100% width and you add padding on the left and right of 20px. It will create a horizontal scrollbar because the element is 100% + 40 px.

So if you are building liquid elements inside a div you would do it like this:

```
#liquidelement {
   width:96%;
   padding:0 2%;
}
```

You need to subtract the padding from the widths, also always use percentages for the padding when doing layouts because it's fluid, not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## 2020

If any of you using Boostrap and came across this question then here's the answer.

### *for* Bootstrap Users

Wrap your `.row` with `.container` or `.container-fluid` and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your issue, the code appears to be correct. However, some elements inside might also affect the exact width and overflow your boundary. Might check all inside elements as well. You can use Firebug or Chrome Inspect Element.

Answer (score 0):

No more than three steps are required here:

1. Scroll the horizontal bar to the right where you can see the extra empty padding.
2. Open an Inspect Element

> This is done by holding `ctrl + shift` then pressing `i`

3. Scroll over all your elements, the element with the extra padding should protrude your pages content into that empty space created.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```css
#wrapper {
   max-width:100%
   width:100vw;
}
```

it work fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question and I know you found your answer
but I say this because I didn't see this anywhere else. maybe this help someone else.

if you use `min-height` in your CSS code, this causes a horizontal or maybe vertical useless scroll bar.
just delete it if it isn't important